# Just starting off with swift/coding on xCode, at what point can I use a segue to take me to my homeVC?

Tags: swift, xcode, button, segue

Was following a tutorial when I came to a halt at not being able to switch to a new VC.

The segue in question: `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHomeVC", sender: self)`

I was trying to use it in the `@IBAction didTapButton` function, but it won't work and I can't figure out where else I would put it. After that button is tapped, when the user is logged in, everything on screen hides, but I want to have it go to homeVC.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class LoginVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    private let companyLogo = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Company Logo White.png")!);
    private let signInLogo = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "SignInText.png")!);


    private let emailField: UITextField = {
        let emailField = UITextField()
        emailField.placeholder = "Email Address"
        emailField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        emailField.autocapitalizationType = .none
        emailField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        emailField.backgroundColor = .white
        emailField.leftViewMode = .always
        emailField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 0))
        return emailField
    }()

    private let passwordField: UITextField = {
        let passwordField = UITextField()
        passwordField.placeholder = "Password"
        passwordField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        passwordField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        passwordField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        passwordField.backgroundColor = .white
        passwordField.leftViewMode = .always
        passwordField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 0))
        return passwordField
    }()

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!


    private let signOutButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Log Out", for: .normal)

        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        emailField.delegate = self
        passwordField.delegate = self


        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
            #selector(keyboardWillChange), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
            #selector(keyboardWillChange), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:
            #selector(keyboardWillChange), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)



        view.addSubview(companyLogo)
        view.addSubview(signInLogo)
        view.addSubview(emailField)
        view.addSubview(passwordField)
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for: .touchUpInside)

        if FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {


            companyLogo.isHidden = true
            signInLogo.isHidden = true
            emailField.isHidden = true
            passwordField.isHidden = true
            button.isHidden = true

            view.addSubview(signOutButton)
            signOutButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 150, width: view.frame.size.width-40, height: 52)
            signOutButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(logOutTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }

    @objc private func logOutTapped(){
        do {
            try FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signOut()

            companyLogo.isHidden = false
            signInLogo.isHidden = false
            emailField.isHidden = false
            passwordField.isHidden = false
            button.isHidden = false

            signOutButton.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        catch {
            print("An error occurred")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()



        companyLogo.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                y: 125,
                                width: 179,
                                height: 141)


        companyLogo.center.x = self.view.center.x // for horizontal
        //myButton.center.y = self.view.center.y // for vertical


        signInLogo.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                            y: companyLogo.frame.origin.y+signInLogo.frame.size.height+150,
                            width: 110,
                            height: 36)
        signInLogo.center.x = self.view.center.x



        emailField.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                y: signInLogo.frame.origin.y+signInLogo.frame.size.height+50,
                                width: view.frame.size.width-40,
                                height: 50)
        emailField.addLayerEffects(cornerRadius: 5)



        passwordField.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                                    y: emailField.frame.origin.y+emailField.frame.size.height+10,
                                    width: view.frame.size.width-40,
                                    height: 50)
        passwordField.addLayerEffects(cornerRadius: 5)



        button.frame = CGRect(x: 20,
                            y: passwordField.frame.origin.y+passwordField.frame.size.height+30,
                            width: view.frame.size.width-40,
                            height: 52)
        button.addLayerEffects(cornerRadius: 4)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
            //emailField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }



    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Continue button tapped")
        guard let email = emailField.text, !email.isEmpty,
            let password = passwordField.text, !password.isEmpty else {
                print("missing field data")
                //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHomeVC", sender: self)
                return
    }




        FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { [weak self] result, error in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }

            guard error == nil else {
                // show account creation
                strongSelf.showCreateAccount(email: email, password: password)
                return
            }

            print("You have signed in")

            strongSelf.signInLogo.isHidden = true
            strongSelf.emailField.isHidden = true
            strongSelf.passwordField.isHidden = true
            strongSelf.button.isHidden = true

            strongSelf.emailField.resignFirstResponder()
            strongSelf.passwordField.resignFirstResponder()

        })

    }

    func showCreateAccount(email: String, password: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Create Account",
                                    message: "Would you like to create an account?",
                                    preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue",
                        style: .default,
                        handler: {_ in

                            FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { [weak self] result, error in

                                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                                    return
                                }

                                guard error == nil else {
                                    // show account creation
                                    print("Account creation failed")
                                    return
                                }

                                print("You have signed in")

                                strongSelf.signInLogo.isHidden = true
                                strongSelf.emailField.isHidden = true
                                strongSelf.passwordField.isHidden = true
                                strongSelf.button.isHidden = true

                                strongSelf.emailField.resignFirstResponder()
                                strongSelf.passwordField.resignFirstResponder()

                            })

        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                        style: .cancel,
                        handler: {_ in

        }))

        present(alert, animated: true)
    }



    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        emailField.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }


    @objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: Notification) {




        guard let keyboardRect = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
                else {
                    return
                }

        if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification || notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification {


            view.frame.origin.y = -245
        } else {

            view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }

    }





}
```

Comment: ** important** I have already connected the segue using the view, allowing me to segue programmatically but I'm willing to change the "@IBAction didTapButton" to allow for this specific button to segue if that Is a better option

Comment: What do you mean by "everything on screen hides, but I want to have it go to homeVC"? Where is it going right now? Have you added views to your homeVC?

Comment: After the didTapButton is clicked this happens: 

strongSelf.signInLogo.isHidden = true
                            strongSelf.emailField.isHidden = true
                            strongSelf.passwordField.isHidden = true
                            strongSelf.button.isHidden = true

This hides the elements on screen, hiding everthing is in the tutorial but Instead I want the didTapButton to take the user to HomeVC. The view doesnt go anywhere but the programmatic segue is not taking us anywhere, I guess because I dont know where to put it although I am comfortable using segues usually

Comment: Have you tried writing //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHomeVC", sender: self) outside the else case; I mean in the scope of guard?

Answer (score 1):

Hello, just to be sure. have you set the segue identifier in your storyboard? 
For navigation to work on calling  `performSegue()`, you have to select a segue in your storyboard, then go to the attributes inspector and give it a name such as “goHomeVC” in your case.

Then in your swift code, to the place where you want to trigger the segue you just named, you need to call the method performSegue(); pass it a segue identifier as well as whatever object you want to send along, and you’re done.

[image]

Comment: Yes, i have the segue identifier in the story board, but i think the code for some reason is prioritizing other events for some reason

https://imgur.com/a/rMRIex7

Comment: ok i figured it out, i had to place the segue above the "print("You have signed in")" statement, obviously lol tank you everyone i appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, since earlier it was inside the else condition, the navigation was never happening. Good luck. :)